# Couldnt iterate all value in array with specific condition?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-webpages

I have to iterate an array with for loop to find it contains specific words in it and add that in Listbox

```
String[] result= ["vicky","vinay@","google@","hello"];


for (l=0 ; l<= result.length; l++)
{
    if(result[l].contains("@"))
    {
         Listbox.Items.Add(result[l]);
    }
}
```

What this does is it gets only first found value I am not getting second value?

Comment: There should be an exception in your code. Loop condition "l<= result.Length;" should be "l< result.Length; "

Comment: Yeah I figured out that that my work is completed Thanks Man

Answer (score 0):

Here it is (but using linq it will be a cleaner solution in this case in my opinion) :

```
        String[] result = { "vicky", "vinay@", "google@", "hello" };
        List<string> StringsResult = new List<string>();

        for(int l = 0 ; l <= result.Length-1; l++)
        {
            if(result[l].Contains("@"))
            {
                StringsResult.Add(result[l]);
            }
        }

        foreach(String s in StringsResult)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write($"{s} ");
        }
```

Output : "vinay@","google@"

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do it with Linq:

```
Listbox.Items.AddRange(result.Where(x => x.Contains("@")).ToList());
```

However, if you just want to do it with a for loop:

```
for(int i=0; i<result.Length;i++)
    if(result[i].Contains("@")) Listbox.Items.Add(result[i]);
```

Or

```
foreach(var item in result)
    if(item.Contains("@")) Listbox.Items.Add(item);
```

Answer (score 0):

its working fine with me without error

```
String[] result = { "vicky", "vinay@", "google@", "hello" };

            var Listbox = new List<string>();
            for (int l = 0; l <= result.Length; l++)
            {
                if (result[l].Contains("@"))
                {
                    Listbox.Add(result[l]);
                }
            }
```